# Are hidden GitHub Pages links findable?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

If I have a private GitHub repo with two public pages

```
example.com/index.html
example.com/my-super-secret-url-362956393.html
```

and it is hosted on a private repo. Obviously, anybody could find `example.com/index.html` as it would be the default link, and could see any pages it links to.

Is there anyway someone could find the secret page without it being directly linked to on a sitemap, or as an  tag on another accessible page?

Comment: Are you concerned about someone brute forcing until they find the link?

Comment: No, it would be like brute forcing trying to find a password, e.g. ```example.com/2s84l3402ngld40xn5lx.html```

Comment: Accessing private repos require either your password or an API. Thus, you would have bigger issues if your account is compromised.

Comment: @astrochun This is about github pages.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because private repos cannot have a github pages (`username.github.io/project`). So what you're referring to is a public page hosted elsewhere and not a standard `gh-pages` hosted through GitHub.

Comment: Perhaps in the past, but now you can: https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages